# How to show week's first and last date as table's first element

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table

I want to show date of first day and last day of week.

Every row would have single day's data.

This is my database table:

```
id a1 a2 a3 a a4 a5 a6 color date
1 2 6 8 45 4 9 6 black 2015-10-11
2 1 3 6 63 3 3 0 black 2015-10-12
3 1 3 6 11 4 3 6 red 2015-10-13
4 1 3 8 35 1 1 3 red 2015-10-14
5 1 1 6 11 4 3 6 black 2015-10-15
6 1 6 6 77 4 3 3 black 2015-10-16
7 2 3 6 63 4 3 1 black 2015-10-17
8 2 2 8 45 4 3 e red 2015-10-18
```

I want to show table like this:

[image]

For that purpose I created this code:

```
<?php
$inr=0;
$color = $query2['color'];
include('config.php');
$query1=mysql_query("select  id, a1, a2, a3, a, a4, a5, a6, color, date from addd");
echo "<table><td>".$query2['date']."</td>";
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
echo "<td>".$query2['a1']."</br>";
echo "".$query2['a2']."</br>";
echo "".$query2['a3']."</td>";
echo "<td style='color:".$query2['color']."'>".$query2['a']."</br><a href='edit.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>e</a>|<a href='delete.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>x</a></td>";
echo "<td>".$query2['a4']."</br>";
echo "".$query2['a5']."</br>";
echo "".$query2['a6']."</td>";
$inr++;
if($inr%8==0)
echo "<tr><td>".$query2['date']."</td>";
}
?>

</tr></table>
```

This code is working fine but the `<td>` of date is not appearing in starting of table.

I am getting result like this:

[image]

Please help me.

1. how to show [date - date+6]
2. how to insert [date - date+6] into first `<td> </td>` of every week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line

```
$query1=mysql_query("select  id, a1, a2, a3, a, a4, a5, a6, color, date from addd");
echo "<table>";
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
 $inr++;
 if($inr%8==0) {
  echo "<tr><td rowspan='8'>".$query2['date']."</td>";
 }
echo "<td>".$query2['a1']."</br>";
echo "".$query2['a2']."</br>";
echo "".$query2['a3']."</td>";
echo "<td style='color:".$query2['color']."'>".$query2['a']."</br><a href='edit.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>e</a>|<a href='delete.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>x</a></td>";
echo "<td>".$query2['a4']."</br>";
echo "".$query2['a5']."</br>";
 echo "".$query2['a6']."</td>";
}
?>

 </tr></table>
```

inside while.because you have used $query2['date'] even before you fetch value from $query1 result

Comment: then date will appear 8 times with all elements

Comment: you can use rowspan=8 in that td so it wont be repeated for 8 rows